# Behavior of higher moments in the bivariate distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, bivariate

Given a bivariate joint distribution of random variable X and Y, $P(X,Y)$, consider the expectation value $E[(X-Y)^n]$ for different n values.

If one observes that while the variance becomes smaller as $n$ is increased within even and odd $n$ series, the even values are hierarchically larger than odd, what does this say about the bivariate distribution I'm considering? Is there a nice intuition for this?

That is, precisely, say one sees something like

$  E[(X-Y)^5]< E[(X-Y)^6]\lesssim  E[(X-Y)^3] < E[(X-Y)^4] \lesssim E[(X-Y)]  < E[(X-Y)^2]$

and similar pattern continues for higher power. Note that here, I wrote $E[(X-Y)^4] \lesssim E[(X-Y)]$ and $E[(X-Y)^6]\lesssim  E[(X-Y)^3]$. Although $E[(X-Y)^4]$ (or  $E[(X-Y)^6]$) seems smaller than $E[(X-Y)]$ (or $E[(X-Y)^3]$), they don't seem much smaller, so I'm not sure whether this is generally true. That is, $E[(X-Y)^4]$ (or  $E[(X-Y)^6]$) is suppressed because it is higher power and $E[(X-Y)]$ (or $E[(X-Y)^3]$) is suppressed because it is odd.

Comment: That look implausible as a general statement (especially if you rescale).  Are you looking a specific distribution for $X$ and $Y$ such as independent standard normals?

Comment: Oh my sincere apology. I didnt mean variance, but rather expectation value. I made proper edits. It’s not a specific distribution, but something I see in a “data” I collected. I did check that it does normalize to 1 as it should

Comment: Ok, I think I figured it out. I think it means the 1-dimensional distribution with "Z=X-Y" as the random variable is symmetric and doesn't have a bump structure in the tail region